# Eliminar filas y enviar texto a un item en un QTableWidget

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqt, qtablewidget

Tengo un problema al tratar de mandar un texto a un item en un tablewidget.

Este es el código que utilizo:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5 import uic 
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Principal(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        uic.loadUi("gif.ui",self)

        self.table.setColumnWidth(0,200)
        print(self.table.item(1,1).text())
        self.s = self.table.item(0,1)
        self.s.setText("s")



app = QApplication([])
p = Principal()
p.show()
app.exec_()
```

y este es error que recibo:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Angel\Desktop\gif.py", line 21, in <module>
p = Principal()
File "C:\Users\Angel\Desktop\gif.py", line 16, in __init__
self.s.setText("s")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'setText'
[Finished in 0.5s with exit code 1]
```

Anexo a esto como puedo hacer para eliminar una fila¿?

archivo .ui

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>800</width>
    <height>600</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <widget class="QTableWidget" name="table">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>40</x>
      <y>150</y>
      <width>641</width>
      <height>281</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="frameShape">
     <enum>QFrame::NoFrame</enum>
    </property>
    <property name="frameShadow">
     <enum>QFrame::Plain</enum>
    </property>
    <property name="lineWidth">
     <number>11</number>
    </property>
    <property name="midLineWidth">
     <number>7</number>
    </property>
    <row>
     <property name="text">
      <string>1</string>
     </property>
    </row>
    <row>
     <property name="text">
      <string>2</string>
     </property>
    </row>
    <row>
     <property name="text">
      <string>3</string>
     </property>
    </row>
    <column>
     <property name="text">
      <string>1</string>
     </property>
    </column>
    <column>
     <property name="text">
      <string>2</string>
     </property>
    </column>
    <column>
     <property name="text">
      <string>3</string>
     </property>
    </column>
    <item row="1" column="1">
     <property name="text">
      <string>kjhkjhj</string>
     </property>
    </item>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>800</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu estas asumiendo que si un QTableWidget tiene n filas y p columnas todos los items son creados, pero no lo es, por diseño tener elementos en campos vacion involucraria gastos de memoria. Asi que en tu caso no esta creado el item `(0,1)`, lo tendras que crear.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic 


class Principal(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Principal, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi("gif.ui",self)
        self.table.setColumnWidth(0,200)

        pos = (0, 1)
        it = self.table.item(*pos)
        if it is None:
            it = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
            self.table.setItem(*pos, it)
        it.setText("s")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    p = Principal()
    p.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

Para remover una fila debes usar el metodo [removeRow()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html#removeRow):

ejemplo:

```
class Principal(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Principal, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi("gif.ui",self)

        self.table.removeRow(1)
```

Por último te recomiendo revisas la documentación de Qt, Qt ya tiene muchos años por lo que lo más probable es que tenga una función para lo que deseas, y por ultimo google siempre te ayudara.